# how to open .docx file in new template with angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, iframe

Below code is successfully opens the .jpeg, .pdf file in new template by using iframe but it failed to open the .docx file,

How can i resolve it?

**Angularjs code:**

```
$scope.openTemplate = function ($fpath) {
        $scope.value = true;
        $scope.imageUrl = $fpath;
        ngDialog.open({
            template: './externalTemplate.html',
            className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
            scope: $scope
        });
    };
```

**HTML code:**

```
<iframe  ng-src="{{imageUrl}}" height="450px">Something wrong...</iframe>
```

Comment: You can't display a `.docx` in a browser. Best thing you can do is provide a link to it (`<a href="{{documentUrl}}">Link</a>`)

Answer (score 0):

I never had tasks like this, but I can suppose next:

Try set response **Content type** HTTP-header to "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" and install **docx-viewer** [like this](http://chrome-office-viewer.en.softonic.com/)